# Python 3.5.1 Introduction to Python 2.1 Mark Clarkson - While Loop Issue

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm working my way through this set of tutorials. In section 3.2a - While Loops the following code is supposed to loop until the user enters the target number (7) then display a congratulations message however regardless of what number is entered Python either gives a right answer or a wrong answer, even 7 will sometimes flag a wrong answer. I know there are other ways to perform this sort of task but I would like to get the code from the tutorial working.

```
targetNumber = 7
guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10 ")
while guess != targetNumber:
    print("Wrong, try again ")
    guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10 ")
    print("Congratulations - that's right!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the target numger to an string before comparison. Also, you should exclude the congratulations message from the loop. I would suggest :

```
targetNumber = str(7)
guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10 ")
while guess != targetNumber:
    print("Wrong, try again ")
    guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10 ")
print("Congratulations - that's right!")
```

The detail is that input returns a string and if you compare a string to an integer, it will always return false.

Comment: Entering 7 still flags "Wrong, try again "

Comment: That's because I made a mistake ;). I edited the post, it should read ```while guess != targetNumber:```

Comment: Bingo! Converting the number to a string is not mentioned yet the code does not work without it!!! Given I'm following a tutorial that seems to be a major oversight!

Comment: @MBM, I highly recommend [Hands-on Python Tutorial by Dr. Andrew N. Harrington](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/index.html). All the code and examples were up to date and accurate when I ran through it few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Python's input function (or raw_input in Python 2.x) returns a string entered by the user.  targetNumber, on the other hand, is an integer.  In the Python Interpreter, try:

```
>>> 7 == "7"
False
```

You need to cast the user's input to an integer first.

```
try:
    guess = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
except ValueError:
    print("That is not a valid number!")
```

Comment: The example worked in 2.x because 2.x input did the conversion behind the scenes with `eval` (which is potentially dangerous).